# running appimage from guest session

Tags: guest-session, appimage

I enabled guest sessions to allow students use ubuntu and have:

- fresh new session after logout
- avoid having them changing anything, installing new software, etc

everything works great, but I cannot run appimages from the guest sessions:
[image: error message]

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: How do you "run appimages" from a non-guest session? Do you have changes in `$PATH` that guest users don't?

Comment: Are they member of the FUSE group? What are you seeing when running AppImages from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

I got a way to make it work by adding `--appimage-extract-and-run`

```
./myapp.AppImage --appimage-extract-and-run
```

This works also for menu items.

Comment: This works! I get some errors, but this made the AppImage work!

Answer (score 0):

Any user can execute an appimage if he has been granted permissions to run the file. If it is set only for the owner or the group, only the owner or a member of the group of the file can execute it. Thus, check whether the executable bit of the appimage is set for "others".